# How to include two attributes in JSON

Tags: java, json, postman

Currently, I'm working on a JSON API using Postman, and I've been able to successfully retrieve attributes, particularly the 'user' attribute.

```
{
  "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "value": {
        "roles": [
          {
            "value": "user"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I now face the issue of only being able to call one attribute from the JSON, and I intend to retrieve two attributes. The system is only allowing me to call the first attribute which is 'user'.

```
{
  "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "value": {
        "roles": [
          {
            "value": "user"
          },
          {
            "value": "admin"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here part of code to fetch values from a JSON API:

```
if (operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value").has("roles")
        && operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")
            .getJSONArray("roles").getJSONObject(0).has("value")) { 
    if (!(operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")
            .getJSONArray("roles").getJSONObject(0).getString("value")
            .trim().equals("")
        || operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")
            .getJSONArray("roles").getJSONObject(0)
            .getString("value").trim() == null)
        && operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")
            .getJSONArray("roles").length() > 0) {
        Value[] userInfo = new Value[1];
        Value value = new Value(
            operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")
                .getJSONArray("roles").getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("value").trim(),
            operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")
                .getJSONArray("roles").getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("value").trim());
        userInfo[0] = value;
        Operations operation = new Operations(
            operations.getJSONObject(i).getString("op").trim(),
            "operations.value.roles.value", userInfo);
        operationsObjArr[i] = operation;
    } else {
        proceed = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this limitation and retrieve both attributes successfully?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand whether the question is how to use a third-party API or how to parse the response/extract data from the response. Can you clarify? For parsing/extracting: why don't you use `ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library or something similar?

Comment: Do note that using variables for repeatedly accessed intermediate expressions can help immensly with the clarity (and understandability of the code). The expression `operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value")` is repeated 7 times and `value.getJSONArray("roles").getJSONObject(0)` is repeated 5 times

Comment: You are accessing `.getJSONObject(0)` two times when assigning `Value value = new Value(...`. I assume that the second one should be `getJSONObject(1)` to get the second value from the list. If that's the case, the question is a typo and can be closed.

Comment: i want to fetch multiple roles from JSON

Comment: Can you add the `Value` and `Operations` class?

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently only reads the first element in the roles array (getJSONObject(0)), to retrieve multiple attributes you need to iterate through the entire roles array. Here is the modified code snippet which will traverse the roles array and add each role to the userInfo array.

```
if (operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value").has("roles")) {
    JSONArray rolesArray = operations.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("value").getJSONArray("roles");
    List<Value> userInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < rolesArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject role = rolesArray.getJSONObject(j);
        if (role.has("value") && !role.getString("value").trim().equals("")) {
            Value value = new Value(
                role.getString("value").trim(),
                role.getString("value").trim()
            );
            userInfoList.add(value);
        }
    }

    if (!userInfoList.isEmpty()) {
        Value[] userInfo = userInfoList.toArray(new Value[0]);
        Operations operation = new Operations(
            operations.getJSONObject(i).getString("op").trim(),
            "operations.value.roles.value",
            userInfo
        );
        operationsObjArr[i] = operation;
    } else {
        proceed = false;
        break;
    }
}
```